# event destination to SNS using AWS cloud formation stack not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ses

Can't create an event destination to SNS using AWS cloud formation stack.

my yml config:

```
SendLog:
      Type: AWS::SES::ConfigurationSetEventDestination
      Properties:
        ConfigurationSetName: !Ref EmailConfig
        EventDestination:
          Name: "Send_Log"
          Enabled: true
          MatchingEventTypes:
            - "delivery"
```

error:

```
Serverless: Operation failed!
Serverless: View the full error output: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stack/detail?stackId=********

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: SendLog - Event destination is not provided. (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: bb88f59d-392e-4d5f-af0a-35fcb25d7b82; Proxy: null).
```

Answer (score 1):

alright! found the solution.

unfortunately, this feature is not yet supported by AWS. although they have a full documentation on it on their [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-configurationseteventdestination.html)
i found out it says it right [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAjqV.png)